# Trying to loop over every tif image in my folder which is the directory

Tags: python, loops

Trying to loop over every tif image in my folder which is the directory,it prints, but doesnt seem to work running the function through every iamge. I am new to python so any help would be appreciated

```
Result = []

def calculation_A(filename):
    data = gdal.Open(filename)

    band = data.GetRasterBand(1)
    arr = band.ReadAsArray()
    rows = len(arr)
    cols = len(arr[0])

    temp = []
    r_temp = []
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if arr[i][j] > -200:
                temp.append(arr[i][j])
                r_temp.append(np.asarray(temp).mean())
                r_temp.append(np.asarray(temp).min())
                r_temp.append(np.asarray(temp).max())
    return r_temp

directory = "C:/Users/valeria.briones/Desktop/New folder/Tmax"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".tif"):
        print(filename)
        Result.append(calculation_A(filename))
print(Result)
```

Comment: Looks like your code lacks proper indentation. If code after `print(filename)` should be also in loop you should keep it on the same indentation level.

Comment: Also your print statement is after your return statement? Also you are doing your calculation twice?

Comment: No just once through all the files, I added print mostly to see if it worked